# SWT Display / Shell terminate and reshow

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, swtchart

I have been trying many different things at making this work and have not been able to. What it is doing is this: The program works fine starting from STARTUP and waits for user input and other stuff. Then it calls this:

```
new Coil_Testing(option);
```

This moves our thread to a new class (Coil_Testing). In this class it will run the test and after it sets up my devices and connects to them it will launch the GUI(appChart). This shows a graph of live information as the test progresses. The test will run it's course and work as it should. After it done with the testing, I call chart.close() and this is my own method and it should **but doesn't** clear the chart's threads and or memory.

Because of this the next time I run the test without terminating the program it gives me a Thread error while calling shell.open().

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid

I am doing it this way because I usually have many test lined up back to back and would be nice not needing to reopen the program over and over.

The "Shell Sleep" message is in the appChart at the end of the show() method.

---

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
<Blank Space>

===========CONTACTOR INFO==========
 1:                  Contactor: 700S-DCP71020Z24 E
 2:                  Date Code: 1423 (Jun 2 - Jun 8)
 3:                       Coil: PD714
 4:                    Voltage: 24VDC
 5:                      Hertz: DC
 6:           Contactor Number: TEST
 7:                    Comment: TEST
=============TEST SETUP===========
 8:               Voltage Type: DC
 9:           Number Of Cycles: 3
10:            Cycle Time (ms): 0
11:           Toggle Test Type: Cold
12:  Hot Coil Refresh Time (M): 5
13:               Toggle Email: FALSE
14:                     PLC IP: 192.168.1.10    Port: 502   
15:      Digital Multimeter IP: 192.168.1.12    Port: 5025  
16:             Ocilloscope IP: 192.168.1.13    Port: 5025  
17:     TEST DEVICE CONNECTIONS
18:                 SETUP EMAIL
19:            Folder Location: C:\Users\<NAME>\Documents\TEST RESULTS FOLDER\Coil Testing
99:                EXIT PROGRAM
Type 1 - 19 to edit or 0 to continue 0

<Blank Space>

Please check setup and unpause the test.
Max Current Found: 0.326633

Cycle 1 out of 3 ... Retries: 0
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Voltage: 24.3465642
Frequency: 0.0
Getting Oscilloscope Data
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Got 7680 of information per pole.
Now Analyzing Close Time and Bounce Time.
Close times: 55.83ms .. 55.73ms .. 55.57ms
Bounce times: 0.00ms .. 0.00ms .. 0.00ms
Max Current: 0.50A
Min Current: -0.03A
Seal Current: 0.47A
Form Factor: 1.00
Shell Sleep
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Open times: 13.96ms .. 14.43ms .. 14.79ms
Reading Resistance
Resistance: 50.31
Cycle Time: 8491



Cycle 2 out of 3 ... Retries: 0
Shell Sleep
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Voltage: 24.4384331
Frequency: 0.0
Getting Oscilloscope Data
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Got 7680 of information per pole.
Now Analyzing Close Time and Bounce Time.
Close times: 55.42ms .. 55.10ms .. 54.95ms
Bounce times: 0.00ms .. 0.10ms .. 0.05ms
Max Current: 0.50A
Min Current: -0.02A
Seal Current: 0.47A
Form Factor: 1.00
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Open times: 10.31ms .. 10.73ms .. 11.15ms
Reading Resistance
Resistance: 50.30
Cycle Time: 8493



Cycle 3 out of 3 ... Retries: 0
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Voltage: 24.3477854
Frequency: 0.0
Getting Oscilloscope Data
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Got 7680 of information per pole.
Now Analyzing Close Time and Bounce Time.
Close times: 55.99ms .. 55.78ms .. 55.52ms
Bounce times: 0.00ms .. 0.00ms .. 0.00ms
Max Current: 0.50A
Min Current: -0.02A
Seal Current: 0.47A
Form Factor: 1.00
Scope Single Ready!
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Open times: 10.05ms .. 10.47ms .. 10.94ms
Reading Resistance
Shell Sleep
Resistance: 50.36
Cycle Time: 8288


Saving output file to C:\Users\<NAME>\Documents\TEST RESULTS FOLDER\Coil Testing\11-13-2015_14-29-15.xlsx
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Writing to INFORMATION
Writing CycleNum to each sheets.
Writing to CLOSE TIME
    L1
    L2
    L3
Writing to BOUNCE TIME
    L1
    L2
    L3
Writing to OPEN TIME
    L1
    L2
    L3
Writing to CURRENT
Writing to COIL INFO
    Resistance
    Voltage
Writing to RETRY SHEET
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep

<Blank Space>

Shell Sleep
===========CONTACTOR INFO==========
 1:                  Contactor: 700S-DCP71020Z24 E
 2:                  Date Code: 1423 (Jun 2 - Jun 8)
 3:                       Coil: PD714
 4:                    Voltage: 24VDC
 5:                      Hertz: DC
 6:           Contactor Number: TEST
 7:                    Comment: TEST
=============TEST SETUP===========
 8:               Voltage Type: DC
 9:           Number Of Cycles: 3
10:            Cycle Time (ms): 0
11:           Toggle Test Type: Cold
12:  Hot Coil Refresh Time (M): 5
13:               Toggle Email: FALSE
14:                     PLC IP: 192.168.1.10    Port: 502   Valid
15:      Digital Multimeter IP: 192.168.1.12    Port: 5025  Valid
16:             Ocilloscope IP: 192.168.1.13    Port: 5025  Valid
17:     TEST DEVICE CONNECTIONS
18:                 SETUP EMAIL
19:            Folder Location: C:\Users\<Name>\Documents\TEST RESULTS FOLDER\Coil Testing
99:                EXIT PROGRAM
Type 1 - 19 to edit or 0 to continue Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
Shell Sleep
0

<Blank Space>

Please check setup and unpause the test.
Max Current Found: 0.326633

Cycle 1 out of 3 ... Retries: 0
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.setFont(Unknown Source)
    at org.swtchart.internal.axis.AxisTickLabels.drawXTick(AxisTickLabels.java:906)
    at org.swtchart.internal.axis.AxisTickLabels.paintControl(AxisTickLabels.java:887)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.UpdateWindow(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Unknown Source)
    at coil_test.appChart.show(appChart.java:82)
    at coil_test.Coil_Testing$1.run(Coil_Testing.java:182)
Scope Single Ready!
```

CLASS appChart

```
package coil_test;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.swtchart.Chart;
import org.swtchart.ILineSeries;
import org.swtchart.ILineSeries.PlotSymbolType;
import org.swtchart.ISeries.SeriesType;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;

public class appChart {

    protected Display display;
    protected Shell shell;
    private Chart closeChart;
    private double[][] arrClose; //Poles | Data
    private ILineSeries closeL1;
    private ILineSeries closeL2;
    private ILineSeries closeL3;
    private Chart bounceChart;
    private double[][] arrBounce;
    private ILineSeries bounceL1;
    private ILineSeries bounceL2;
    private ILineSeries bounceL3;
    private Chart openChart;
    private double[][] arrOpen;
    private ILineSeries openL1;
    private ILineSeries openL2;
    private ILineSeries openL3;
    private Chart currentChart;
    private double[][] arrCurrent;
    private ILineSeries inrush;
    private ILineSeries seal;
    private double[] arrCycle;
    private boolean updateRequired = false;
    private boolean closeRequired = false;
    private boolean run;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            appChart window = new appChart();
            window.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public appChart() {
        /*Display display = Display.getDefault();

        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
    }

    public void show(){
        display = Display.getDefault();

        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                run = true;
                while (run) {
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
                    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(updateRequired){
                                closeChart.update();
                                bounceChart.update();
                                openChart.update();
                                currentChart.update();

                                closeChart.redraw();
                                bounceChart.redraw();
                                openChart.redraw();
                                currentChart.redraw();

                                closeChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();
                                bounceChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();
                                openChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();
                                currentChart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();

                                updateRequired = false;
                            }
                            if(closeRequired){
                                shell.close();
                                shell.dispose();
                                Display.getDefault().close();
                                run = false;
                                closeRequired = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                System.out.println("Shell Sleep");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        thread = null;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(SWT.NO_TRIM); // SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP
        shell.setSize(1280,1024);
        shell.setLocation(1281,0);
        shell.setLayout(null);
        shell.setMinimumSize(1280, 1024);

        closeChart = new Chart(shell, SWT.NONE);
        closeChart.setBounds(0, 0, 1264, 256);
        closeChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setText("");
        closeChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Time (ms)");
        closeChart.getTitle().setText("CLOSE TIME");
        closeL1 = (ILineSeries)closeChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L1--");
        closeL1.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255, 0, 0));
        closeL1.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        closeL2 = (ILineSeries)closeChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L2--");
        closeL2.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 255, 0));
        closeL2.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        closeL3 = (ILineSeries)closeChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L3--");
        closeL3.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 0, 255));
        closeL3.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);

        bounceChart = new Chart(shell, SWT.NONE);
        bounceChart.setBounds(0, 256, 1264, 256);
        bounceChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setText("");
        bounceChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Time (ms)");
        bounceChart.getTitle().setText("BOUNCE TIME");
        bounceL1 = (ILineSeries)bounceChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L1--");
        bounceL1.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255, 0, 0));
        bounceL1.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        bounceL2 = (ILineSeries)bounceChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L2--");
        bounceL2.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 255, 0));
        bounceL2.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        bounceL3 = (ILineSeries)bounceChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L3--");
        bounceL3.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 0, 255));
        bounceL3.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);

        openChart = new Chart(shell, SWT.NONE);
        openChart.setBounds(0, 512, 1264, 256);
        openChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setText("");
        openChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Time (ms)");
        openChart.getTitle().setText("OPEN TIME");
        openL1 = (ILineSeries)openChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L1--");
        openL1.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255, 0, 0));
        openL1.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        openL2 = (ILineSeries)openChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L2--");
        openL2.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 255, 0));
        openL2.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        openL3 = (ILineSeries)openChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "--L3--");
        openL3.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 0, 255));
        openL3.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);

        currentChart = new Chart(shell, SWT.NONE);
        currentChart.setBounds(0, 768, 1264, 256);
        currentChart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).getTitle().setText("");
        currentChart.getAxisSet().getYAxis(0).getTitle().setText("Amps (A)");
        currentChart.getTitle().setText("CURRENT");
        inrush = (ILineSeries)currentChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "Inrush");
        inrush.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255, 0, 0));
        inrush.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);
        seal = (ILineSeries)currentChart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.LINE, "Seal");
        seal.setLineColor(new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 255, 0));
        seal.setSymbolType(PlotSymbolType.NONE);

        arrCycle = new double[0];
        arrClose = new double[3][0];
        arrBounce = new double[3][0];
        arrOpen = new double[3][0];
        arrCurrent = new double[2][0];
    }

    public void updateClose(int cycle, double l1, double l2, double l3){
        double[][] temp = new double[3][cycle];
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < cycle - 1; i++){
                temp[j][i] = arrClose[j][i];
            }
        }
        arrClose = temp;
        arrClose[0][cycle-1] = l1;
        arrClose[1][cycle-1] = l2;
        arrClose[2][cycle-1] = l3;

        updateChart();
    }

    public void updateBounce(int cycle, double l1, double l2, double l3){
        double[][] temp = new double[3][cycle];
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < cycle - 1; i++){
                temp[j][i] = arrBounce[j][i];
            }
        }
        arrBounce = temp;
        arrBounce[0][cycle-1] = l1;
        arrBounce[1][cycle-1] = l2;
        arrBounce[2][cycle-1] = l3;

        updateChart();
    }

    public void updateOpen(int cycle, double l1, double l2, double l3){
        double[][] temp = new double[3][cycle];
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < cycle - 1; i++){
                temp[j][i] = arrOpen[j][i];
            }
        }
        arrOpen = temp;
        arrOpen[0][cycle-1] = l1;
        arrOpen[1][cycle-1] = l2;
        arrOpen[2][cycle-1] = l3;

        updateChart();
    }

    public void updateCurrent(int cycle, double inrush, double seal){
        double[][] temp = new double[2][cycle];
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < cycle - 1; i++){
                temp[j][i] = arrCurrent[j][i];
            }
        }

        arrCurrent = temp;
        arrCurrent[0][cycle-1] = inrush;
        arrCurrent[1][cycle-1] = seal;

        updateChart();
    }

    private void updateChart(){
        int cycleSize = arrCycle.length;
        if(cycleSize < arrClose[0].length || cycleSize < arrBounce[0].length || cycleSize < arrOpen[0].length || cycleSize < arrCurrent[0].length){
            cycleSize = Math.max(arrClose[0].length, arrBounce[0].length);
            cycleSize = Math.max(cycleSize, arrOpen[0].length);
            cycleSize = Math.max(cycleSize, arrCurrent[0].length);

            double[] temp = new double[cycleSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < cycleSize; i++){
                temp[i] = i+1;
            }
            arrCycle = temp;
        }

        closeL1.setYSeries(arrClose[0]);
        closeL2.setYSeries(arrClose[1]);
        closeL3.setYSeries(arrClose[2]);
        bounceL1.setYSeries(arrBounce[0]);
        bounceL2.setYSeries(arrBounce[1]);
        bounceL3.setYSeries(arrBounce[2]);
        openL1.setYSeries(arrOpen[0]);
        openL2.setYSeries(arrOpen[1]);
        openL3.setYSeries(arrOpen[2]);
        inrush.setYSeries(arrCurrent[0]);
        seal.setYSeries(arrCurrent[1]);

        closeL1.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        closeL2.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        closeL3.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        bounceL1.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        bounceL2.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        bounceL3.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        openL1.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        openL2.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        openL3.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        inrush.setXSeries(arrCycle);
        seal.setXSeries(arrCycle);

        updateRequired = true;

        /*
        closeChart.update();
        bounceChart.update();
        openChart.update();
        currentChart.update();
         */
    }

    public void close(){
        closeRequired = true;
    }
}
```

CLASS Coil_Testing

```
package coil_test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import device_com.Device_Connection;
import device_com.Device_IO;
import device_com.Device_Utility;
import device_com.PLC_IO;
import device_com.PLC_Type_Enum.Variable_Type;
import email_user.Email_User;

public class Coil_Testing {

    private void test() throws IOException{
        <Setting Up Devices and Variables>

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                chart = new appChart();
                chart.show();
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        <Collect Data From Test And Update Chart>

        <Write To Excel>
        <Send Email>

        chart.close();
        thread = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Calling `Thread.sleep` in the User Interface thread is an extremely bad idea, this will stop all UI code from running while the thread is sleeping (including the `syncExec` calls).

Comment: @greg-449 Ok the two Thread.sleep in my code are from online helps on how to get my UI to work and my test does not need to be refreshed more than 1 seconds anyways. Is there any alternative?